# tail -1000f doesn't show the same output as tail -1000

Tags: tail

I am trying to execute

```
tail -100000f MXMLExchangeMonitoring_Mx3.log | egrep "INTENTO.*Workflow" | cut -d ":" -f "3" | cut -c 3,4,5,6 | awk '{if($1>20)print$1}'
```

and I'm getting nothing.

but with

```
tail -100000 MXMLExchangeMonitoring_Mx3.log | egrep "INTENTO.*Workflow" | cut -d ":" -f "3" | cut -c 3,4,5,6 | awk '{if($1>20)print$1}'
```

I get the expected:

```
212
45
29
463
544
556
543
1115
830
802
119
95
33
31
194
170
127
97
```

I need the `-f` so I can read the new numbers bigger than 20 that are appearing in the file.

Decreasing the amount of lines is also an option, I can start with a small amount, for example -100.

The `tail -f` works fine for:

```
tail -100000f MXMLExchangeMonitoring_Mx3.log | egrep "INTENTO.*Workflow" | cut -d ":" -f "3"
```

Comment: I don't think you can combine arguments like that.  Does `tail -f -100000` work for you?

Comment: `awk` is buffering a lot of data. `tail` without `-f` terminates, `EOF` happens to each pipe, and the awk outputs all it has and exits. The `-f` makes everything wait until `tail` exits (which it won't), or for `awk` to collect a thousand or so lines. Gnu/awk has a `fflush()` function -- try that after each `print`.

Comment: Something in the pipeline is buffering all the data, which is delaying output (because the `tail -f` never ends, so the pipework never clears). Can you test one additional case: `tail -f ... | egrep | cut | cut` to show whether the second cut or the awk is an issue. Output to terminal and pipes should automatically be line-buffered, but something is not. `awk` can do anything that `egrep` and `cut` can do, and has a `fflush()` function, so `tail -f | awk ...` would be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Commands with *stdout* not a terminal (here those are commands before a pipe) will have stdio C functions (like `fwrite()`) do block (aka full) buffering. Here's some description of the behavior in [`setvbuf(3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/setvbuf.3#DESCRIPTION) (this is a standard C and [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) function, but the description is taken from the GNU variant. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) might suggest exact behavior is implementation-defined):

> Normally **all files are block buffered**. If a stream refers to a
> **terminal (as *stdout* normally does), it is line buffered**. The standard
> error stream *stderr* is always unbuffered by default.

All commands in a succession of pipelines except the last one are potentially affected: they get the normal behavior of block-buffering their output.

---

Here's a method working at least on Linux and FreeBSD.

- Some commands (`tail`) behave as "expected" with this

  Nothing to do.
- others (`grep`) have options about this

  For GNU and *BSD (even Mac OS X) `grep` there's a built-in `--line-buffered` option to change its behavior
- others (`cut`) don't.  There are workaround, probably system specific

  On GNU as well as FreeBSD systems (but apparently not other *BSD variants) there is a libc wrapper tool [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/stdbuf.1#EXAMPLES) intended for this:

  > [**EXAMPLES**](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/stdbuf.1#EXAMPLES)
  >
  > ```
  > tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
  > ```
  >
  > This will immediately display unique entries from access.log
- `awk` is at the end of the pipeline and outputs to a terminal so isn't affected (ie: it's already line-buffered)

  Should that be needed later, this tool includes the `fflush()` command to be used for the same effect.

All of these tools being dynamically linked should support the use of `stdbuf -o L` even when not using some of their dedicated feature, but better not use a libc wrapper when it's possible not to.

Given all this, and with `stdbuf` installed, this revised line should behave as intended (I broke it into multi-lines to have it more easily readable):

```
tail -100000f MXMLExchangeMonitoring_Mx3.log |
    egrep --line-buffered "INTENTO.*Workflow" |
    stdbuf -o L cut -d ":" -f "3" |
    stdbuf -o L cut -c 3,4,5,6 |
    awk '{if($1>20)print$1}'
```

In some simpler filtering cases, just reordering the commands to keep only a command whose behavior can't be easily changed as the last would be enough. But without `stdbuf`, having two `cut` in the pipeline won't cut it.